# Increase DOM element or use http request instead

Tags: html, css, optimization

I want to know which is best method for fast loading website.
I know,

- more http requests, slow will be the website
- more DOM element, slow will be the website

Now, 
 I am confuse in following methods:

First, i used extra `div` element to show **drop-shadow** effect like this

```
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #eee">
  <div style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #ccc">
    <div style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid #aaa">
      <div style="height:98px;width:98px;border:1px solid #999">
        <div style="height:96px;width:96px;border:1px solid #777">
       hello world
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second, i used `background image` to show **drop shadow** effect like this

```
<div style="background-image=url(drop-showdow.png)">
  hello world
</div>
```

More `http-request` and more more `dom element` is not good for optimized website. What to do? and WHY?

Comment: first off, take out the inline styles and put then in a linked css file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use CSS?

```
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px #777;
```

For something like this, which adds appearance rather than being a required feature, just use plain CSS. If people are still using old enough browsers that don't support it, tough break for them. The Internet as a whole cannot advance if we spend every day worrying about people still in the Stone Age.

Comment: Google maps does actually use that `div` technique